# need for decoupling capacitor in a Fender Bassman

Tags: amplifier, decoupling-capacitor, tube

why is there no need for a decoupling capacitor in the second preamp stage (highlighted section)?
I would imagine a 0.02-400V capacitor just before the grid of the second half of the valve to block high DC voltage from reaching the grid

[image]

Comment: Where do you suggest it should be fitted?

Comment: like this -> https://imgur.com/Bq6yHyv

Comment: Don't grids always need a DC path?

Comment: @user253751 not really, but you'd be building a capacitive voltage divider with the anode/cathode|grid vs grid|grid feed if you put a capacitor between grid and feed. That sounds... bad.

Comment: @Sarkipinty the place where you want to put it is *inside* the tube?!

Comment: The anode of triode 1 and the grid of triode 2 are connected externally between pins 1 and 7 but breaking this connection with a capacitor would mean that you need to add bias back to the grid of triode 2. You can't AC bias a grid since the grid leakage current would eventually turn off the tube.

Comment: @MarcusMüller of course, i want to cut open the tube and solder a capacitor in, then suck out the air and join the glass back together with a blowtorch :)

Comment: @Sarkipinty ah, separate grid connections make that feasible :)

Answer (score 0):

The anode of triode 1 and the grid of triode 2 are connected externally between pins 1 and 7 but breaking this connection with a capacitor would mean that you need to add bias back to the grid of triode 2. You can't AC bias a grid since the grid leakage current would eventually turn off the tube. – ScienceGeyser